# Change main branch in Sonarqube without deleting branch

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web, sonarcloud, sonarqube-api

I am trying to change my main branch in Sonarqube from `master` to `mainline` as I have been doing my analysis on `mainline` for the past few months.

This post below in the Sonar community says that I have to delete the `mainline` branch then rename the `master` branch.  The problem with this approach is that I would lose all of my history which I do not want to do.
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-change-the-main-branch-in-sonarqube/13669/37

Is there anyway to change the main brach to another branch without losing all of our scan history?

Using:
Developer Edition - Version 9.2.1

[Picture of Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMdSN.png)

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned here https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-change-the-main-branch-in-sonarqube/13669?page=2

Comment: Yes, I linked that thread in the question. It requires you to delete your old branch which I don't want to do because I want to keep the history

Comment: Update: this feature under development as of April 2023 & is expected in 10.X. There is a tile for setting a new main branch on the roadmap https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarqube/roadmap/.
This comment has additional details: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-change-the-main-branch-in-sonarqube/13669/55

Comment: Released now in 10.2

Answer (score 3):

Found [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-change-the-main-branch-in-sonarqube/13669/58?page=3) on the sonar source community. Seems like this was missing feature and being released on 10.2

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an administrator of the project.

1. Navigate to the right side of the panel, open the Project Settings combo box and select "Branches & Pull Requests":

   [image]
2. You will see the branch list. Under "Actions", expand the cogwheel icon and click to "Rename branch" so feel free to rename the default `master` to for example `develop` or `mainline` in your case.

   [image]

   Beware. If `develop` already exists in the list of branches, you have to first delete `develop` and then rename `master` to `develop`, otherwise it is not possible to change the main branch. In such a case, you need to run the build again, i.e. publish a new analysis to Sonar.

Once this is done, Sonar will display the `develop` branch as a default one.

Comment: I think this fails to satisfy this part of OP question: _without losing all of our scan history_.

Comment: The OP can create a new branch (`archive`) and do the renaming: `mainline` -> `archive` and `master` -> `mainline`. I'd tested it first on different branches, though.